# Jupiter 5.9.1 ParamiterizedTest not passing test cases

Tags: junit, junit5, spring-test, junit-jupiter

I have a method generated test case:

[image]

And the test method:

[image]

I got following error

[image]

My pom file:

[image]

Comment: In general: Please add code and configuration as text, not as images. Otherwise you prevent people from actually trying out your examples, which lowers the probability of someone looking into your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because jupiter-params version is over jupiter-engine version. After I made them both 5.9.0, it works fine.